# Existe alguna clase o funcion para poner formato de moneda en un input text?

Tags: php, html

Necesito hacer un formulario para registrar productos a una base de datos, queria saber si existe alguna función para que al escribir por ejemplo: 10 Salga asi: $10.00.

Comment: dado que el input está del lado del cliente habría que ver cómo quieres armarlo visualmente y si incluye validación, podes usar por ejemplo https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar a concatenar un '$' antes del numero introducido, y hacer una comprobación por si el numero no tiene decimales añadirle '.00'

Una función basica:

```
function moneda($moneda) {
    if (strpos($moneda,'.')) {
        $str = '$'.$moneda;
    } else {

    $str = '$'.$moneda.'.00';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Seguramente haya una forma mejor de hacerla pero quizas te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas una versión de PHP mayor a 4.3.0 puedes emplear la función [**money_format**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php). Esta función toma dos parámetros, el formato y un valor numérico.

Para ponerle el signo $ y dos decimales podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$numero = 125.236;
echo money_format('$%.2n', $numero); // $125.24
```

"$" sería una cadena arbitraria y "%.2n" sería el valor con 2 decimales.

Otra opción de poner el signo $ sería utilizando la función [**setlocale**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php):

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
$numero = 125;
echo money_format('%.2n', $numero); // $125.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres formatear un número como moneda no necesitas ninguna extensión. Todos los browsers modernos soportan el objeto [intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

Si recibes un número `1500000.5` y quieres formatearlo con puntos como separador de miles, coma como separador decimal, y signo euros:

```js
const numero = 1500000,
  numero_formateado = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  }).format(numero);
document.querySelector('#input_numero').value = numero;
document.querySelector('#input_formateado').value = numero_formateado;
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-evenly;">
  <label>numero:<br><input type="number" id="input_numero" /></label>

  <label>numero formateado:<br><input type="text" id="input_formateado" /></label>
</div>
```

Si lo que queres es que el comportamiento se mantenga luego de la interacción con el usuario (cosa que no pueda borrar el signo de moneda, por ejemplo) puedes usar por ejemplo [AlpineJS con el plugin mask](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/mask#money-inputs):

```
  <input type="text" x-mask:dynamic="'€ '+$money($input)" placeholder="€ 0.00">
```

(Ahí puedes anteponer el signo de moneda que prefieras, use euros como ejemplo)

```css
.demo {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border-color: #d8dee9;
}

.demo input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Alpine Plugins -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/mask@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<!-- Alpine Core -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo" x-data="">
  <input type="text" x-mask:dynamic="'€ '+$money($input)" placeholder="€ 0.00">
</div>
```

Manipular el contenido del input no es algo trivial. Si quieres usar eventos y reescribir lo que haya escrito el usuario, tendrías que detectar además en qué posición fue el último keyup, porque en otro caso lo estarás llevando una y otra vez al inicio o al final del número, y eso es muy molesto.

Por otro lado, me imagino que lo que la persona escriba querrás enviarlo de vuelta al backend, y querrás enviarlo como número, no como texto formateado. Usando el mismo ejemplo de arriba, puedes hacer un data-binding tal que en otro input (que para este ejemplo está visible, pero en tu caso de uso estaría oculto) se vaya reflejando el valor numérico del texto formateado. A la hora de enviar el formulario, es este último el que realmente se toma en cuenta:

```css
.demo {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border-color: #d8dee9;
}

.demo input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Alpine Plugins -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/mask@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<!-- Alpine Core -->
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo" x-data="{
      valor:'',
      get parsed() {
        return this.valor.replace(/[^\d,]+/g,'').replace(',','.')
      },
      set parsed(val) {
      
      }
      }">
  <input type="text" x-model="valor" x-mask:dynamic="'€ '+$money($input,',','.')" placeholder="€ 0.00">
  <input type="number" x-model="parsed">
</div>
```